# memory mapped file в java

Tags: java

Пакет `nio` предоставляет memory mapped file channel, с помощью которого можно получить benefit при работе с крупным файлом.
Документация говорит, что в этом случае команды работы с файлом делегируются OS и доступ происходит вне java heap.
Возникает вопрос, а *non-mapped* file разве не также работает? Разве он копирует сначала файл в адресное пространство java процесса?

Единственным недостатком признается возможность fault страницы памяти (при которой её нет в памяти). Настолько ли это критично, что все используют обычные *non-mapped* file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Классические операции с файлами (non-mapped file) не используют механизмы отображения и при чтении данных из файла копируют их в указанный участок памяти в рамках текущего процесса. При этом данный участок памяти никак не связан с исходным файлом.

Отображения обычно работают быстрее, и проблем с ними я почти не замечал.
Во всяком случае на osx, `openSuse` и Win7/10 активная работа с файлами через отображения не вызывала никаких проблем, кроме мелочи с unmap, которую было легко исправить и не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Comment: так а почему почти всегда использую классические операции?)

Comment: Классические операции работают достаточно хорошо и нет нужды тратить время на переделывание legacy кода. Проект может требовать поддержки старых jre, в которых nio/nio2 нет.

Answer (score 0):

Классическая работа с файлами предполагает 1) вызов процессом ядра, 2) ядро отправляет запрос драйверу, 3) поток блокируется до получения уведомления о готовности данных (процессор переключается на другой поток/процесс), 4) поток уведомляется о доступности данных, запрошенный блок копируется в адресное пространство ядра, 5) блок данных копируется из адресного пространства ядра в пользовательское адресное пространство, 6) системные классы могут один или более раз копировать данные в массив `byte[]`.

Преимущество при классической работе с файлами - возможность вычитать большой блок данных за один syscall. Требуется явный вызов метода для отправки измененных данных на диск (ОС может их оставить в буфере "грязных" страниц, если обратное явно не затребовано от программы).

При работе через mmap страницы читаются по 4kB. Причем при подгрузке страницы в кеш ОС используются прерывания, ядро приостанавливает работу потока и переключается на загрузку file backed страницы памяти в ОЗУ. 4kB запросы снижают throughput дисковой подсистемы.

Преимущество при работе с mmap получается в случае, если происходит многократный доступ к данным в пределах страницы памяти (4kB), так что major page fault ошибки не возникают.  В общем случае при работе с mmap код может просто изменять содержимое буфера, ОС сама решает в какой момент сохранить измененную страницу (dirty page) на диск.